# Specify the resource a virtual machine has

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, vmware, virtualization

I am using a Mac having this:
[image]

I have installed `VMware Fusion`, in one virtual machine `Ubuntu` has been installed with this ressource:
[image]

And here is what is displayed in `System Monitor` of Ubuntu:

[image]

I need to do some experiments under Ubuntu... I am not sure how to specify well the resource used. May I say "The experiments are run *under a virtual machine configured to use 2 processor cores among 8 processor cores and 3GB RAM on a PC of 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7 and 8GB RAM*? Is there a correct and compact way to express this?

Comment: I hardly doubt you need that many resources for Linux, but whatever. How many processors did you choose? You cannot see that on this VMWare detail page. And a Mac is no PC...

Comment: So, how could I check how many processors Linux uses?

Comment: Take a look at /proc/cpuinfo in linux.

Comment: Your description seems OK there isn't any shorter way to say this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend checking the system's specifications from within the virtual machine. Instructions on how to access the specifications can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55609/how-do-i-check-system-specifications)

Comment: Thanks, I have checked `System Monitor` and added the screenshot in OP... How could I express `2.50GHz x 2`?

Comment: `2.50GHz x 2` is good enough in my oppinion

Answer (score 1):

Just mention the specifications that Ubuntu is reporting, and mention that it was ran in a virtual machine. VMs are designed to allocate the resources they need, so it shouldn't matter what the host machine is.